# Hyper-V Port forwarding in Nested Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, port-forwarding, hyper-v

I'm having a Windows server 2016 installed on VMware workstation 15. 
In windows server 2016, I've Hyper-V. Hyper has 2 virtual machines i. Ubuntu ii. Windows 10.

My question here is:
How can I access Hyper-v vm's from my physical machine(Windows 10) using port forwarding ? I want to access the VM's through RDP (for windows vm) or through ssh (for linux vm).

Setup is like this:

Windows 10 -> VMware workstation -> Windows server 2016 -> Hyper-V -> VM.

I'm using NAT Networking in VMware workstation.

I want to access VM from Windows 10 using Port forwarding.
For Eg.
If I access Windows server 2016 ip address on port 80, I get forwarded to VM's IP address on port 80 which is hosting my apache server.

Thank you :)

Comment: When you say "access the VMs" what do you mean exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment to clarify this point.

Comment: You should be able to access the VM by connecting to the intranet IP address assigned to the VM.  This does not require you to forward any ports.

Comment: What networking option are you using for VMware Workstation?  NAT, bridged, etc?

Comment: @Ramhound I know Sir but I intentionally want to port-forward. I want that when I access the IP address of the Windows Server 2016 on a particular port from my windows 10 machine, I get forwarded to the VM's ip address.
Like if I access Windows server 2016 ip address on port 80, I get forwarded to VM's IP address on port 80 which is hosting my apache server.

Comment: @essjae I'm using NAT for my VMware workstation.

Comment: You don’t need to port forward within your network.  It won’t do anything unless your accessing it outside of your intranet.  What you want doesn’t make sense logically

Comment: @Ramhound My VM is on another network (10.10.10.1) and the windows server is on a different network (192.168.206.134)